# "Cannot destructure property 'reservations' of 'this.props.reservation' as it is undefined" and filter it ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

I can't get the reservations from my server as I get my rooms. I use almost the same method but I can't figure out why I can't access them. I need to take the reservations from my server and filter it matching the user ID with the one stored in the reservation schema.

This is how I access the items:

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getReservations } from '../actions/bookAction';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Dashboard extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        getRooms: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        getReservations: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        room: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        reservation: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getReservations();
        this.props.getRooms();
    };

    render() {

        
        const { reservations } = this.props.reservation || {} 

        const { rooms } = this.props.room;

        const { isAuth, user } = this.props.auth;

        const DashUnauth = (
            <>
            <TopCont>
                <h1>Questa è un'area riservata.</h1>
                <Link className="btn-primary" to="/signin">Accedi</Link>
                <Link className="btn-primary" to= "/signup">Registrati</Link>
            </TopCont>
            
            </>
        );

        const DashBasic = (
            <>
            <div className="dash-cont">
                <img src={profile} alt="profilo" className="profile-img"/>
                <div className="profile-stuff">
                    <h1>Ciao </h1>
                    <h3>Bentornato nella tua dashboard.</h3>
                    <h3>Da qui puoi accedere alla gestione delle tue prenotazioni e tante altre funzionalità.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="tab-cont">
                <TabNav tabs={['Prenotazioni', 'Strutture Caricate']} selected={ this.state.selected } setSelected={ this.setSelected }>
                    <Tab isSelected={ this.state.selected === 'Prenotazioni' }>
                        <Table hover>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Struttura</th>
                                    <th>Ospiti</th>
                                    <th>CheckIn</th>
                                    <th>CheckOut</th>
                                    <th>Prezzo /notte</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            {reservations.map(({ room_name, prezzo, checkin_date, checkout_date, ospiti }) => (  
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{room_name}</td>
                                        <td>{ospiti}</td>
                                        <td>{checkin_date}</td>
                                        <td>{checkout_date}</td>
                                        <td>{prezzo}$</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            ))}
                        </Table>
                    </Tab>

                    <Tab isSelected={ this.state.selected === 'Strutture Caricate' }>
                        <div className="tab-cont-button">
                            <Button><Link to="/profile-upgrade">Diventa Oste</Link></Button>
                        </div>
                    </Tab>
                </TabNav>
            </div>
            </>
        );

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    room: state.room,
    auth: state.auth,
    reservation: state.reservation
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getRooms, deleteRoom, getReservations })(Dashboard);
```

At this point it throws me an error like `Cannot destructure property 'reservatios' of 'this.props.reservations' as it is undefined`.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Hey so I answered thinking this was a syntax mistake but now I'm not sure what your intention is -- is your data actually located at `this.props.reservations.reservations` or at `this.props.reservations`?

Answer (score 1):

You've got your syntax mixed up.  Right now you are looking for a *property* `reservations` on `this.props.reservations` so you are looking for `this.props.reservations.reservations`.  This gives you an error because you are treating `this.props.reservations` as an `object`, but it might be `undefined` and you cannot destructure `undefined`.

You want to *either* destructure `reservations` off of `this.props` or access the property, not both.

```
const reservations = this.props.reservations || {}
```

or

```
const { reservations = {} } = this.props
```

Same for `room`!

**Edit**: Now I am seeing that the prop name which you define in `propTypes` is `reservation` (singular) not `reservations` (plural).

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong to write, I edited my post and added my mapStateToProps const and export. Thanks for the patience!